# How to import jQuery in WordPress plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I just wrote a plugin but I don't know how to include javascript to WordPress here. Can any body help me, I am making a form, which will store into database.

```js
jquery(document).ready(function() {
  jquery('#type_of_moving').click(function(){
    jquery(".option_wrap").css("display", "block");
    jquery('#disable_option :not(:selected)').attr('disabled','disabled');           
    var select_type = jquery('.option_wrap :selected').val();            
    jquery('#type_of_moving').val(select_type);
  }); 
           
  jquery(document).ready(function(){
    var current = 1,current_step,next_step,steps;
    steps = jquery("fieldset").length;
    jquery(".next").click(function(){
      jquery(".previous").css("display", "block");
      current_step = jquery(this).parent();
      next_step = jquery(this).parent().next();
      next_step.show();
      current_step.hide();
    });
    jquery(".previous").click(function(){
      current_step = jquery(this).parent();
      next_step = jquery(this).parent().prev();
      next_step.show();
      current_step.hide();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Put your code in a file, `main.js` as example. Upload it to your plugin root folder. And put this code to your main plugin file to make WordPress load your Javascript code at frontend.

```
function wp_plugin_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/main.js', array('jquery') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_plugin_enqueue_scripts' );
```

P/s: Make sure your javascript is valid. `jquery` is different from `jQuery`

Comment: i did it same way but its not taking

Comment: Did you check for console log? Did WordPress load your script correctly without 404 Not Found? And remember `jquery` is diferrent from `jQuery`, double check it again.